# Is `ServletContext` interface implemented by any classes inside Tomcat server?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm currently learning Java EE using Tomcat 9 server, with focus on the `ServletContext` interface.

I want to know what classes implement `ServletContext` interface, so I checked the [official Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-). But the official documentation does not list any classes that implement `ServletContext` interface. And I noticed that `ServletContext` interface is `public`, therefore I was thinking the `ServletContext` interface must have been implemented by some classes inside tomcat server.

Because I'm relatively new to Java EE and Tomcat, therefore I'm not sure if my assumption is correct. Also, if my assumption is indeed correct, could someone please tell me where I can find the source code that implement `ServletContext` interface? I would love to have a look at the source code and try to understand how it really works.

Comment: Yes the implementation will be given by the Tomcat container. However I have no idea if it is a concrete Class or an anonymous implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is how it works. JavaEE is a specification so all you have is interfaces. The implementation is provided by the containers.

In tomcat it's implemented by [`ApplicationContext.java`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationContext.java)

Comment: may i ask what is your search strategy? do I have to be very familiar with the tomcat implementation to find something or is there are smarter way?

Comment: you should not worry about tomcat implementation at all 99.99% of the time. just learn the specification. that's the reason for that specification to exist, each implementor might use different approaches, but the behaviour and API is already defined and all implementors must follow it (the only differences, and that's the other 0.01% of the cases, is for what the specification does not define).

Comment: @CaptainAmerica I just looked in one of my projects that has a dependency on tomcat what class implements  `ServletContext`(and then googled for the link), no familiarity with anything is required. You can add a dependency to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina in one of your projects and look for any implementation that interests you in your IDE(you can also configure maven to download sources and javadoc). I also agree with albert_nil, you only need it if it interests you, for actually doing something you only need the specification.

Comment: thanks @albert_nil & Oleg for the heads up! really appreciate it!